# Create partitions based on column values in sql

Tags: sql, database, partition

I am very new to sql and query writing and after alot of trying, I am asking for help.
As shown in the picture, I want to create partition of data based on is_late = 1 and show its count (that is 2) but at the same time want to capture the value of last_status where is_late = 0 to be displayed in the single row.

The task is to calculate how many time the rider was late and time taken by him from first occurrence of estimated time to the last_status.

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: as long as you have the same columns you can combine two (or more) different queries with UNION

Comment: please tag your dbms and enter sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query

```
SELECT 
       rider_id,
       task_created_time,
       expected_time_to_arrive,
       is_late,
       last_status,
       task_count,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, expected_time_to_arrive, last_status), 0), 114) AS time_delayed
FROM
  (SELECT 
       rider_id,
       task_created_time,
       expected_time_to_arrive,
       is_late,
       SUM(CASE WHEN is_late = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY rider_id ORDER BY rider_id) AS task_count,
       ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY rider_id ORDER BY rider_id) AS num,
       MAX(last_status) OVER(PARTITION BY rider_id ORDER BY rider_id) AS last_status
   FROM myTestTable) t
WHERE num = 1
```

*[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3ade129dec5e01c390d84bc29a743404)*